# Is it possible to get unsrt + abbrv bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, sorting

Is there a ready made BibTeX bibliography style file that both: (1) prints author names abbreviated (like `abbrv`) in the references section and (2) sorts references numerically in citation order (like `unsrt`)? Furthermore, is there one such style compatible with `natbib`?

Comment: Side remark: is that really a good idea? Unsorted listings with abbreviated author names can make referring to the reference list (in dead tree format; so you can't hide behind hyperref) rather difficult.

Comment: @Willie, well this is what I was asked to produce, so I don't have much choice. But could you elaborate on why is this a bad idea? Why an unsorted but non-abbreviated list would be any better?

Comment: Ah, perhaps I misunderstood you since you mentioned `natbib`. I thought you want a citation format that has in-line `[JoSm]` and in the reference section `[JoSm] Johnson, A and B Smith, blah`. and have that listed in citation order. Looking more closely at LockStep's answer suggest you actually want just to abbreviate the author first names in the reference section and  cite by number. Then in that case my objection won't apply. I'll leave why "what I thought you meant" is a bad idea as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I see, yes, I wasn't clear enough. In the text I'll be using numerical references since otherwise, as you point out, unsorted references don't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I didn't find a ready-made bst-file, but seem to have managed to combine `unsrt` and `abbrv` by myself. Since I can't upload the new bst-file, here's what I did:

1. Copy `unsrt.bst` into a working directory and rename it (later, this file should go into your local texmf tree);
2. In the new file, look for `FUNCTION {format.names}`. In the seventh code line of this function, look for `ff~` and replace it with `f.~` (because that's the way it is in `abbrv.bst`);
3. Replace the macros for month/journal names after `FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }` with their counterparts of `abbrv.bst`.

I've tested the resulting bst-file, and it seems to work. The relevant parts of `plainnat.bst`, `abbrvnat.bst` and `unsrtnat.bst` resemble those of the standard bst-files at first glance, so I guess the above method should also work to create a natbib-compatible bst-file that suits your request.

P.S.: With biblatex, your request would basically boil down to `\usepackage[sorting=none,firstinits=true]{biblatex}`. ;-)

Comment: +1 for pointing out how biblatex makes this question trivially easy

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! If anybody needs it, I uploaded the custom bst file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oz2f1t7sjwxoh5f/unsrt_abbrv_custom.bst?dl=0). Just download it to your working folder, and put `\bibliographystyle{unsrt_abbrv_custom}` in your preamble.

Answer (score 17):

There is a ready made BibTeX style file that both: (1) prints author names abbreviated (like `abbrv`) in the references section and (2) sorts references numerically in citation order (like `unsrt`): `ieeetr.bst`.
According to [Choosing a BibTeX style](http://www.reed.edu/cis/help/latex/bibtexstyles.html) it is one of the seven standard styles that come with LaTeX, but I do not know if it is compatible with `natbib`.

Comment: +1 -- `ieeetran`s formatting is somewhat different from `unsrt` and `abbrv`, but it *does* abbreviate and sort in citation order.

Comment: There is also a natbib-compatible version of IEEEtran, called [IEEEtranN.bst](https://www.bibtex.com/s/bibliography-style-ieeetran-ieeetrann/)