# Sorted and brief bibliography format

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to get unsrt + abbrv bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5053/is-it-possible-to-get-unsrt-abbrv-bibliography)

I am looking for a setting for a bibliography with two properties:

1. Items appear in the order of citation, so that in the document the citations are [1], [2], [3]...
2. The bibliography itself is as brief as possible - No extra fields, no long names, etc.

In other words the bibliography style should combine `unsrt` with `abbrv`, preferably with some control on displayed fields, to make the entries even shorter.  I haven't found such an option in the default styles or in natbib.

Comment: A way to combine `unsrt` and `abbrv` is described [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5053/is-it-possible-to-get-unsrt-abbrv-bibliography/5056#5056).