# biblatex: Abbreviated author names?

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

When using biblatex, how can you obtain abbreviated first names for authors in the bibliography (i.e. like the `abbrv` bibtex)?

I've been trying to look everywhere in the manual, but so far no luck.

Comment: `firstinits=true`

Comment: Didn't you remember [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5053/is-it-possible-to-get-unsrt-abbrv-bibliography/5056#5056) to one of your former questions? ;-)

Comment: Gah! It was your answer that finally made me consider switching to biblatex.. but I didn't used it *then*.. only until now I remember. :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134535/biblatex-authoryear-style-in-text-citations-display-first-name-initials-for-ce)

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio This does not appear to be a duplicate of the question you suggest. This question here is concerned with obtaining initials instead of full first names in the bibliography. Your suggested duplicate is about the name disambiguation feature that may at times print more than just the last name in citations.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Loading `biblatex` with the package option `giveninits=true` will just print the initial of the author's first name.

Note that this will not work in somewhat old versions, and you must use (the now-deprecated) `firstinits=true` option instead, which accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Aha, now I can see the option. Strange that is buried in the list of “internal options” and without any mention to `abbrv`. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Juan the thing is, there are _so many_ options, that it can be difficult to know where to look for the relevant ones!

Comment: In recent versions this option has been renamed to `giveninits`. The deprecated name continues to work, but it produces a warning. It is strongly advised to switch to the new name.

Comment: In the manual an "abbreviate=true" is also mention, but in my case non of the three results in abbreviated author names.

Answer (score 2):

While this is way to late, it might still help someone:

If you are actually looking for emulating the abbrv style, then there is this simple solution of adding `style=trad-abbrv` to the package options (before any other).