# biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` with the `authoryear` style and two of my bibliography entries include the initials of the first author when cited in-text (`R. Chen and Holmes, 2006` and `B.J. Chen et al., 2008` shown below).  Only these two entries are affected:

[image: In text citation displays initials]

I thought that there may be a problem with my bibfile, but this issue still occurs when the bibliography entries are included directly in a LaTeX document, as shown in the MWE below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
hyperref=true,
firstinits=true, % render first and middle names as initials
maxcitenames=3,
maxbibnames=99,
style=authoryear,
dashed=false, % re-print recurring author names in bibliography
natbib=true,
useprefix=true, % for inclusion of 'de' 'da' in surname
urldate=long,
backend=biber
]{biblatex}



% No unit separator after publication year:
\usepackage{xpatch}\xapptobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\nopunct}{}{}

% No month for publication year:
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}

% Use single quotes around titles:
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
%\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{{\let~\,#1}} % insert thin spaces between author initials
%\renewcommand*{\bibnamedelimd}{\addlpthinspace} % insert thin spaces between author initials
\renewcommand*{\bibinitdelim}{} % no spaces between author initials (requires biber)
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace} % insert a comma between author and year in-text citations
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace} % comma as separator in bibliography, not full stop
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} % remove 'in:' preceding article title

% Place volume number within parentheses:
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \setunit*{\addnbspace}% NEW (optional); there's also \addnbthinspace
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Spacing in bibliography:
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{12pt}
\setlength{\bibhang}{16pt}% the hanging indent

\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{type}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{Available at: \url{#1}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Article{Example_Article_1,
  Title                    = {Title 1},
  Author                   = {Smith, A. B. and Jones, D. C.},
  Year                     = {2012},
  Month                    = {Oct},
  Number                   = {1},
  Pages                    = {42},
  Volume                   = {10},
  Journal                  = {Example Journal},
}

@Article{Example_Article_2,
  Title                    = {Title 2},
  Author                   = {Smith, A. B. and Jones, D. C.},
  Year                     = {2012},
  Month                    = {Oct},
  Number                   = {1},
  Pages                    = {42},
  Volume                   = {10},
  Journal                  = {Example Journal},
}

@Article{Chen_2006,
  Title                    = {Avian influenza virus exhibits rapid evolutionary dynamics},
  Author                   = {Chen, R. and Holmes, E. C.},
  Year                     = {2006},
  Addendum                 = {[Online]. Available at: \url{example.com} (Accessed: 01 January 2013)},
  Month                    = {Dec},
  Number                   = {12},
  Pages                    = {2336--2341},
  Volume                   = {23},
  Journal                  = {Mol. Biol. Evol.},
}

@Article{Chen_2008,
  Title                    = {The influenza virus M2 protein cytoplasmic tail interacts with the M1 protein and influences virus assembly at the site of virus budding},
  Author                   = {Chen, B. J. and Leser, G. P. and Jackson, D. and Lamb, R. A.},
  Year                     = {2008},
  Addendum                 = {[Online]. Available at: \url{example.com} (Accessed: 01 January 2013)},
  Month                    = {Oct},
  Number                   = {20},
  Pages                    = {10059--10070},
  Volume                   = {82},
  Journal                  = {J. Virol.},
}

\end{filecontents}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\parencite{Example_Article_1}
\parencite{Example_Article_2}
\parencite{Chen_2006}
\parencite{Chen_2008}

\printbibliography[title=References]

\end{document}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

My setup consists of TeX Live 2012 and `biblatex` 1.7-1 on Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

By default, `biblatex` adds first name initials if different authors share the same last name. To turn off this behaviour, add the package option `uniquename=false` to your example. See section 4.11.4.1 of the [manual](https://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for details.

[image]

Comment: How can I turn this behaviour on for just one author? For example, if both Mary Leakey and Louis Leakey are well-known names in their academic circles, but I just cite Louis, I'll want something like (L. Leakey 1956), so that the reader knows which Leakey without going into the bibliography section.