# Biblatex authoryear style & giveninits options - conflicting options warning

Tags: biblatex, warnings

I want to use initials in authoryear style instead of full given names. I tried:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,hyperref=true,giveninits]{biblatex}
```

It works properly but produces the warning:

```
Conflicting options.
```

How to properly customize authoryear style then?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The full warning message I get in the `.log` is

```
Package biblatex Warning: Conflicting options.
(biblatex)                '<namepart>inits' conflicts with 'uniquename=full'.
(biblatex)                Setting 'uniquename=init' on input line 10.
```

This tells you that since you only want given/first name initials with the option `giveninits`, you can't get full uniquename disambiguation if need be (as automatically requested by the `authoryear` style with `uniquename=full`). The message goes on to say that the option will be set to

```
uniquename=init
```

to allow for name disambiguation at least by name initials.

If you don't want the warning in the first place, just load `biblatex` with `uniquename=init` from the start.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,uniquename=init,giveninits]{biblatex}
```

---

If you don't want name disambiguation at all, use `uniquename=false` instead (see [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864) for example).