# Biblatex entries with acute accent have wrong format in citation

Tags: biblatex, accents

I want to cite a book from Albert-László Barabási. In the text the format ('last name of author', 'year') should be used, but the citation is printed in the format ('first name' 'last name', 'year').

I found out that the behavior is related to the "acute accents" in his name. When the BibTeX entry is changed from `author = {Barab\'{a}si, Albert-L\'{a}szl\'{o}}` to `author = {Barabasi, Albert-Laszlo}` the citation has the correct format ('last name', 'year').

How can this behavior be changed to print the 'normal' format?

Comment: When I use `author = {Barab\'{a}si, Albert-L\'{a}szl\'{o}}` with `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`, I got a correct`[Barabási, 2013]` reference. -- What is the style you are using ?

Comment: I use the following setup: `\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,bibencoding=auto]{biblatex}`.

Comment: Using Sharelatex, I got a correct `Barabási, 2013`. Please provide code for a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: See also [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864) even though in this case the solution was not to turn off the disambiguation feature, but to fix a typo in the `.bib` source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause. It was a typo in second biblatex entry:
`author = {Newman, Mark and Barabási, Alberto-László}` 
instead of
`author = {Newman, Mark and Barabási, Albert-László}` (Alberto vs. Albert).

When both entries are cited the behavior occurs. Fixing the typo fixes the citations.

I guess the first name is written to distingues between two authors with the same last name.