# Cite authors with same last but different first names

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I want to cite the following Paper: http://cjp.sagepub.com/content/20/3/310.abstract 
Authors are:

```
Carter, David L
Carter, Jeremy G
```

How can I get LaTex to cite `Carter and Carter 2009` instead of `D.l. Carter and J.G. Carter 2009`

I am using Mendely for the literature and it is generating the bibtex file:

```
@article{Carter2009,
abstract = {Policing in the post-9/11 era is experiencing a philosophical change that is expanding community- and problem-oriented policing to include the broader philosophy of intelligence-led policing (ILP). Building on the British experience, the application of ILP to American policing has been complicated by a number of challenges. Although stimulated by 9/11, the movement toward ILP is being furthered by a number of federal public policy initiatives. As a result of these diverse demands, law enforcement must revisit operational policies and creatively adjust their organizations to reflect this new paradigm. This article provides insight on the conceptual background of ILP, public policy standards, and the integration of ILP with community policing.},
author = {Carter, David L and Carter, Jeremy G},
doi = {10.1177/0887403408327381},
isbn = {9781843923398},
issn = {1043-9463},
journal = {Criminal Justice Policy Review},
number = {3},
pages = {310--325},
pmid = {15341350},
title = {{Intelligence-Led Policing}},
url = {http://cjp.sagepub.com/content/20/3/310.abstract},
volume = {20},
year = {2009}
}
```

Comment: Use the option `uniquename=false`, see [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864)

Comment: It doesn't make much of a difference, but I would prefer `author = {Carter, David L. and Carter, Jeremy G.},`. The `isbn = {9781843923398},` points to a 288 page book of the same title written by Jerry Ratcliffe, and not the article, so is confusing (luckily, the ISBN is rarely shown for an `@article`).