# Changing reference style in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,
            natbib=true,
            url=false,        
            doi=false,         
            isbn=false,
            backend=biber,
            bibstyle=numeric,
            maxbibnames=1,
            mincitenames=1,
            maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\begin{document}
Text \citep{Eliasson1991, Bravi2017}
\input{Reference/Bibliography}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

my bibliography.bib:

```
@article{Eliasson1991,
author = {Eliasson, Ann-Christin and Gordon, Andrew M and Forssberg, Hans},
doi = {10.1111/j.1469-8749.1991.tb14943.x},
isbn = {0012-1622 (Print)},
issn = {14698749},
journal = {Developmental Medicine {\&} Child Neurology},
keywords = {Cerebral Cortex,Cerebral Cortex: physiopathology,Cerebral Palsy,Cerebral Palsy: diagnosis,Cerebral Palsy: physiopathology,Child,Hemiplegia,Hemiplegia: diagnosis,Hemiplegia: physiopathology,Humans,Isometric Contraction,Isometric Contraction: physiology,Motor Neurons,Motor Neurons: physiology,Motor Skills,Motor Skills: physiology,Neurologic Examination,Neurologic Examination: instrumentation,Psychomotor Performance,Pyramidal Tracts,Pyramidal Tracts: physiopathology},
month = {nov},
number = {8},
pages = {661--670},
pmid = {1916022},
title = {{Basic Coordination of Manipulative Forces of Children With Cerebral Palsy}},
url = {http://doi.wiley.com/10.1111/j.1469-8749.1991.tb14943.x},
volume = {33},
year = {1991}
}

@article{Bravi2017,
author = {Bravi, Riccardo and Cohen, Erez J. and Martinelli, Alessio and Gottard, Anna and Minciacchi, Diego},
doi = {10.3389/fnint.2017.00021},
issn = {1662-5145},
journal = {Frontiers in Integrative Neuroscience},
keywords = {augmented feedback,human motor control,laterality of motor control,sensorimotor integration,timing of action},
month = {sep},
pages = {21},
publisher = {Frontiers},
title = {{When Non-Dominant Is Better than Dominant: Kinesiotape Modulates Asymmetries in Timed Performance during a Synchronization-Continuation Task}},
url = {http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fnint.2017.00021/full},
volume = {11},
year = {2017}
}
```

I have two problems with this:

(1) The citation names appear more than 1, I need only one and followed by et.al (first picture)

(2) The citation names for Eliasson for example include the first name (A.C) but another citation do not - see other citation. I dont know why this happens? I only need the last name like the others. [image: see example]

(3) I do not like the reference style (second picture). how can i change to nature style: (Author. Journal title. Journal **21**, 557–62 (2011).)

[image: here]

Comment: Could you post something we can compile?  We don't have the input file. B.t.w., inputting a bibliography with `biblatex` is done through the command `\addbibresource{xxxx.bib}`.

Comment: Please consider asking only one question per question: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864. (1) looks like it could be solved with `uniquelist=false` https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864, (2) looks like `uniquename=false` https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864. For (3) you might want to have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nature

Comment: I must add that I find Author-Year citations together with a numeric bibliography pointless. The numbers in the bibliography don't mean anything if you don't use them to cite the references.

Comment: @bernard I have added the input file. I am not sure about the addbibresource as this works fine and addbibresource gives error

Comment: @moewe thanks for the links, helps half of it. However I cannot use the nature style you've given, when I change style = nature instead of authoryear, it gives me error. about the authoryear and numeric, i agree, however, i need to put the numbers as they need to know how many references I have used throughout

Comment: What error do you get? Do you have `biblatex-nature` installed? There are more elegant ways to count the items in a bibliography than a numeric style and I firmly believe that the number of items in the bibliography is not correlated with the quality of a scientific work - at least not in a way that would make it useful to count the number of items when evaluating the merit of the work. And if someone thinks the number of bibliography items is a useful metric, they should have to count them themselves.

Comment: @moewe I am using Overleaf and I put the nature.bbx and nature.cbx in the main file. However, if I remove the bibstyle=numeric, i get a different error:

Package biblatex Error: Bibliography m
acro 'cite' undefined.

Comment: The style should already be installed, don't add the files manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81577/discussion-between-sharah-and-moewe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Nature style, you need [`biblatex-nature`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nature)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=nature, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: a citation and bibliographic reference in Nature style: "Sigfridsson, E. & Ryde, U. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry **19**, 377–395 (1998)."]

This also works brilliantly on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/btqwrxdsgdps

If you insist on Author-Year citations and `natbib` commands, you need

```
\usepackage[style=nature, citestyle=authoryear, backend=biber, natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

That still works fine on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/jvqbxkzcnqdc

Comment: I see, i think this probably won't work with natbib command citep and citet. I need the citation to be author year but the referencing to nature style, i guess not possibe

Comment: @Sharah This also works with the `natbib`-like commands if you must, just add `natbib=true`. If you insist on Author-Year citations, which are pointless with Nature style, `\usepackage[style=nature, citestyle=authoryear, backend=biber, natbib=true]{biblatex}` works fine for me.

Comment: ohhhhh yess i forgot about that. I think I know referencing more clearer now, it has always been hazy for me on how it works. Thanks so much! Hopefully my phd thesis will turn out well.