# biblatex citation includes given name, how can I get rid of it?

Tags: biblatex

I have following literature in my `.bib` file:

```
@inproceedings{lang2017earth,
title={Earth observation for humanitarian assistance},
  author={Lang, Stefan and Schoepfer, Elisabeth and Zeil, Peter and Riedler, Barbara},
  booktitle={GI Forum--J Geogr Inf Sci},
  volume={1},
  pages={157--165},
  year={2017}
}
```

When I try to cite it with `\parencite{}` or with `\citet{}` it always appears with the name of the author in the .pdf file:

> (Stefan Lang, Schoepfer, et al., 2017)

**I want to get rid off the "Stefan"**

same here

```
@article{lang2015earth,
  title={Earth Observation for Humanitarian Operations},
  author={Lang, Stefan and F{\"u}reder, Petra},
  journal={GI\_Forum},
  volume={2015},
  pages={384--390},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Verlag der {\"O}sterreichischen Akademie der Wissenschaften}
}
```

I cite it with `\citet{...}` and it appears like this in the .pdf:

> Stefan Lang and Füreder (2015)

and again "Stefan" appears!

**What can I do against this, because all the other citations work perfectly except of these two.**

Comment: Is there another author called Lang in your bibliography? `biblatex` has a feature to disambiguate ambiguous family names which means that it may add a given name initial or write out the entire given name to avoid confusion as to which "Lang" is meant. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864

Comment: Note that for the purposes of the `uniquename` disambiguation `Knuth, Donald`, `Knuth, Donald E.` and `Knuth, D. E.` are three different people and `biblatex` would try to disambiguate them accordingly. So it may well be that you don't have *another* Lang in the usual meaning of the word, but just another form of the same Lang's name, e.g. `Lang, Stefan` and `Lang, S.` or `Lang, Stefan R.` or ...

Comment: Any news here? As the question stands now it is very likely a duplicate of the one I linked and if nothing happens in due time I will vote to close as such. But it would be great if you could give a short heads-up and tell us if it worked.

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate since there were no developments here. If the duplicate did not help, please update your question with a complete example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows how `uniquename=false` did not help. I'll happily vote to reopen if you ping me in that case.