# Citation adding a random full stop? Lyx & Bibtex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, lyx

To preface I am a complete beginner using lyx to finish my thesis so please be patient with me.

I am using bibtex to place my references and then connecting this to my lyx file. Take for example the reference below. The lyx document has been set to Biblatex (natbib mode). When citing Shillers reference as in the screenshot it appears as (R. Shiller, 1989). It should be (Shiller, 1989). Why is it adding the the "R."?

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to have another Shiller in your biliography? In this case biblatex just tries to differentiate them.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134535/biblatex-authoryear-style-in-text-citations-display-first-name-initials-for-ce. You need to get LyX to load `biblatex` with the `uniquenames=false` option.

Comment: As David mentions for all we know you need to add `uniquename=false` to your `biblatex` options. Did that work for you? (Do you know how to do that with LyX? Go to *Document > Settings > Bibliography* and add `uniquenames=false` to *Options* under *Citation Style*).

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate of the standard `uniquename` question. If you are having trouble getting this to work with LyX, just ping me and edit the question and I will vote to reopen.