# Show only surnames in citations with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm working on a thesis and decided to use `biblatex` for citation and reference. I use Jabref to organize the `.bib` file and implemented it into my document in the following way:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

The problem is now that I want the citations only to show the author's last names, which doesn't always work. Examples:

```
 author    = {Johnson, Jesse C. and Souva, Mark and Smith, Dale L.}
```

is shown as

> J. C. Johnson, Souva, and Smith (2013)

in the document and

```
 author    = {Linzer, Drew A. and Staton, Jeffrey K.}
```

as

> Linzer and J. K. Staton (2015).

Where does this inconsistency come from and how do I avoid that? Most citations are correct (in the sense that first names are ignored).

Please have in mind that I'm not a programmer but just an ordinary user.

Comment: `biblatex` will add initials to disambiguate between two authors with the same family name but different given names. If you cite `J. C. Johnson` and `A. B. Johnson`, `biblatex` adds the initials to make sure that your readers know that the two Johnsons are different. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864

Comment: Note that `style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear,` is equivalent to the shorter `style=authoryear,`

Comment: Does `uniquename` do what you want? If so, a short heads-up would be appreciated; if not, you may want to edit your question with more details and explain how `uniquename` does not work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Because you gave no [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) -- please add an MWE or MWEB in your next question, it helps us to help you! -- I have to guess a little bit.

Please see the following mwe (I added an fictional bib file with package `filecontents` only to get an compiling mwe, you use your own .bib file):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Johnson,
  author    = {Johnson, Jesse C. and Souva, Mark and Smith, Dale L.},
  Publisher = {Pearson},
  Title     = {Physics for Scientists \& Engineers},
  Year      = {2014},
  Date-Added = {2015-10-05 12:23:12 +0000},
  Date-Modified = {2015-10-05 12:23:50 +0000},
}
@book{JohnsonE,
  author    = {Johnson, David C. and Einstein, Albert},
  Publisher = {Pearson},
  Title     = {Physics for Scientists \& Engineers},
  Year      = {2014},
  Date-Added = {2015-10-05 12:23:12 +0000},
  Date-Modified = {2015-10-05 12:23:50 +0000},
}
@article{Linzer,
  author    = {Linzer, Drew A. and Staton, Jeffrey K.},
  Title     = {Physics for Scientists \& Engineers},
  Year      = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

Some \cite{Johnson}, 
%\cite{JohnsonE} % <========================================= uncomment!
and \cite{Linzer}.

%\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Now please uncomment the line

```
%\cite{JohnsonE} % <========================================= uncomment!
```

to

```
\cite{JohnsonE} % <========================================= uncomment!
```

and compile again three times. Now the result is:

[image: second result]

As you can see, now there are two bib entries with the familyname Johnson, but different firstnames. That is the reason why biber adds the initials of the firstnames to create different author names in the bibliography to give you entries you can sure identify ...

As @AlanMunn mentioned in his comment: It's important to note here that `biblatex` can't distinguish between authors who are in fact the same author if their names in the relevant `.bib` items are different. So e.g. if you have `Johnson, David C.` in one and `Johnson, David` in another they will still get initials. Also that you can turn off this behaviour by using the `uniquename` option with one of its various values ...

Comment: It's important to note here that `biblatex` can't distinguish between  authors who are in fact the *same* author if their names in the relevant `.bib` items are different.  So e.g. if you have `Johnson, David C.` in one and `Johnson, David` in another  they will still get initials.  Also that you can turn off this behaviour by using the `uniquename` option with one of its various values. To turn it off completely use `uniquename=false` (which seems to be what the OP wants).

Comment: So there is no option to choose whether you want to include initials or full names or surnames only. This seems like a bizarre way of doing it. Clearly whether you have given enough details to unambiguously identify the author cannot be judged by biblatex and it is very strange that it even attempts to do this (There could be uncited authors with similar names in the field how would it know. Either way a much better way to tell the author apart is by linking the publication which should be linked to their ORCID).