# Brothers as authors - Biblatex does not format correctly

Tags: biblatex

so for my academic paper I have one book to cite from which is written by brothers (P. Hüwe & S. Hüwe). The citation style my university wants is for to authors to be diveded by a slash: (Hüwe/Hüwe 2019).

This citation stlye works, but unfortunatly not in this particular case where both authors share the same last name, because it also prints out their first names.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ 
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},             
} 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}



\begin{document}
\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{/}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{/}

normal document text

\cite{Hüwe.2019} \\Doenst work
\cite{Yerpude.2019} \\works


\endgroup
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Result:]

Anyone knows why this is?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864

Comment: Note that the name format `last-first` has been renamed and that the preferred form would be `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}`. `finalnamedelim` and `multinamedelim` are also context sensitive nowadays so that you shouldn't have to work with redefinitions in the document body and `\begingroup...\endgroup`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `uniquename=false` option takes care of this problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ 
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},             
} 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\addbibresource{test.bib}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@article{Huewe.2019,
    author = {Hüwe, P. and Hüwe, S.},
    title = {title},
    year = {2019}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{/}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{/}

normal document text

\cite{Huewe.2019} \\Doenst work



\endgroup
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works, thanks! Unfortunatly, it does not within a table environment. do you have any clue why?

Comment: @spqx If you use the option as shown in this answer it should work everywhere. That is to say `\cite` and related commands (not `\fullcite` and the bibliography) will not show given names or given name initials. If it turns out that despite the option you get to see given name initials in some situations, please reproduce this undesirable behaviour in an MWE and report it as a bug at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues