# Stop full name of second author when using \cite{}

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to cite an article with two authors.
The maximum amount of names to two:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxcitenames=2, sorting=nyt, maxbibnames =99, hyperref=true, uniquelist=false, datelabel=comp]{biblatex}
```

The reference is as:

```
@article{NUTS,
    title = "The No-U-Turn Sampler: Adaptively Setting Path Lengths in Hamiltonian Monte Carlo",
    author = "Hoffman, Matthew and Gelman, Andrew",
    year = "2014",
    volume = "15",
    journal = "Journal of Machine Learning Research"
}
```

I cite the article in text as follows:

```
Bla bla bla \cite{NUTS} bla bla.
```

Which gives me:

> Bla bla bla Hoffman and Andrew Gelman 2014 bla bla.

How do you avoid the second authors name being cited in full?
Desired output:

> Bla bla bla Hoffman and Gelman 2014 bla bla.

Comment: I can't say for sure without an MWE () that reproduces the undesirable output, but I would bet on the `uniquename` disambiguation feature. You probably have another work authored by another *Gelman* (it might indeed even be the same *Gelman*, just in a different form: `Gelman, Andrew` and `Gelman, Andrew J.` are two different names to `biblatex` even if they refer to the same person). Try `uniquename=false`, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864

Comment: For most intents and purposes the option `hyperref=true,` is no better than the default setting `hyperref=auto,`. The two option differ only in the behaviour when the package `hyperref` is not loaded: `hyperref=true,` will throw a warning, `hyperref=auto` will just silently accept that. In particular both settings produce links if and only if the `hyperref` package is loaded. In current versions of `biblatex` the option `datelabel` is deprecated, it has been replaced by `labeldate`. `sorting=nyt` is already the default if you load `style=authoryear,`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the link to the MWE meta page in my first comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864

Comment: @moewe, thanks for the answer. It was the uniquename option that did the trick. I have set the option to False as of now, but I should probably be more consistent in my bibliography. I will definitely check out the MWE, such that my questions are easier to answer in the future :)

Comment: Very good. Since `uniquename=false,` solved your problem I vote to close as a duplicate of the question I linked above. (It's an interesting question whether you *should* be consistent in the bibliography. On the one hand it is certainly nice to have a consistent bibliography where the same name always appears in the same form. On the other hand I can see why one would want to stick to the form in the source as closely as possible.)

Comment: Do I have to do anything or has it been closed?

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate of the `uniquename=false` question and a few other people agreed with that vote so that the question is now closed as a duplicate.