# Conflict options (Package biblatex Warning)

Tags: biblatex, incompatibility

I facing this compile warning:

```
Package biblatex Waning: Conflicting options.          main.tex, line 82
'<namepart>inits' conflicts with 'uniquename=full'. Setting 'uniquename=init' on input line 82
```

where my `main.tex, line 82`:

```
77 \usepackage{tikz}
78 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc} 

82 \begin{document}
```

I didn't have any `\begin{document}` in other places.

My `biblatex` setting:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear, dashed=false,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,giveninits]{biblatex}
```

Comment: The line numbers aren't particularly relevant. What are your `biblatex` settings? Please consider posting a complete, *yet minimal* document that reproduces the warning and shows your `biblatex` settings.

Comment: @moewe, thanks. `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear, dashed=false,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,giveninits]{biblatex}` is my biblatex setting, if I am correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following MWE reproduces the warning

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear,
  giveninits]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> ```
> Package biblatex Warning: Conflicting options.
> (biblatex)                '<namepart>inits' conflicts with 'uniquename=full'.
> (biblatex)                Setting 'uniquename=init' on input line 12.
> ```

The `<namepart>inits` part of the message might be a bit confusing. In this case it refers to the option `giveninits` that the MWE loads.

So the warning is telling your that the options `giveninits` and `uniquename=full` are not compatible. `uniquename=full` allows `biblatex` to add name initials or the full name to citations to make (family) names unique. The `uniquename` option is shown in action in [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864) and discussed in great detail in the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) (§4.11.4 *Name Disambiguation*, pp. 305-311).

With `giveninits`, which means that given names will always be shortened only to initials, it is not useful to use the full name for disambiguation.

The warning message already tells you one solution. Add

```
uniquename=init,
```

to your load-time options. Then `biblatex` will at most try to add initials to disambiguate names in citations. If you don't want the feature at all, use

```
uniquename=false,
```

instead.