# Cite paper with 2 authors with the same surname as "Surname and Surname", not "A. Surname and B. Surname"

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am writing a document where I need to cite a paper by two authors who share a surname (they are, in fact, married). Biblatex is currently introducing their initials in the citation, but astronomy convention is to just cite their surnames.

My MWE illustrates the issue. I need to maintain their initials in the bibliography, but cite them as "Strom and Strom (1994)" in the body of the text. Is there a simple way to do this?

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Strom1994,
  author =  {{Strom}, K.~A. and {Strom}, S.~E.},
  title =   {Astro Paper},
  journal =   {A\&A},
  year =    {1994},
}

\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{Strom1994}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Overleaf output of above MWE]

Comment: Have you tried the `astron.bst` Astronomy BibTeX file? It might be on your system (in mine it is in `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texm-dist/bibtex/bst/beebe/astron.bst`). It is one of an extensive collection of BiBTeX style files gathered by Nelson Beebe. I have not tried it.

Comment: Unfortunately, not only am I writing my thesis with a Miktex back end, but I need to use the Cardiff Uni style files for the bib. I am just looking to make this one (well, 2) references also match standard astro formats.

Comment: You need the option `uniquename=false`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864.

Comment: Thank you. That solved it. Clearly skimmed over it thinking it was uniquelist.