# Suppress first name with \citet{}

Tags: biblatex

I'm quite new to LaTeX and I'm really sorry if this is a super easy question, but I didn't find a solution to this specific problem.

I have a book with two authors that I'd like to cite in my text. And I would like to see something like:

> Following Smith and Smith (2006, p. 2),

but instead what I'm seeing is:

> A. Smith and P. Smith (2006, p.2)

I'm using `\citet{key}` and

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib,style=apa,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

Is there any way to omit the initial character of the first name?

Comment: You have tagged your question with both `biblatex` and `natbib`. `biblatex` and `natbib` are two (fundamentally incompatible) bibliography/citation packages. Which one do you use? The solution *crucially* depends on the approach you use. It would be ideal if you could show us a short example document that reproduces what you are seeing with as little code as possible (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Then we would know immediately what packages you use and can test our solutions.

Comment: If you are using `biblatex` it might be https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864

Comment: Do you load the `biblatex` package with the option `natbib`?

Comment: Sorry I know my question wasn't too good...I'll try my best to give a MWE as fast as possible. In my head I'm using `\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib,style=apa,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}`. Maybe this already helps a little

Comment: `style=apa,citestyle=authoryear` is a bit of an unusual combination. Either you want APA style, in which case you need only `style=apa,`or you don't want APA style, in which case `style=authoryear,` might be more appropriate than a mixed form like `style=apa,citestyle=authoryear`. `biblatex-apa` implements APA style as closely as possible and can therefore be hard to customise if you don't want real APA style. Since you are using `biblatex` https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864 should help.

Comment: thank you very much!! Already helped a lot!!

Comment: Does that mean https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864 answered your question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this query as a duplicate of [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134535/biblatex-authoryear-style-in-text-citations-display-first-name-initials-for-ce)