# Short last names appear with initials with biblatex/biber and authoryear

Tags: biblatex, biber

When I cite a paper of an author with a short last name like `\autocite{li2018}`, biblatex/biber include initials when rendering it in author-year.

This is my setting in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp,citestyle=authoryear-comp,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=false,date=year]{biblatex}
```

What would be the right setting to make sure, that only the last name and year are rendered and not the initials?

Comment: This is not standard behavior and it does not happen when I test it myself with your settings. Are you sure that you are not citing multiple people with the same last name and different first names?

Comment: Without a short yet fully compilable example document that reproduces the behaviour (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) we can only guess. My guess would be that you want `uniquename=false`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864 or the `biblatex` documentation for background.

Comment: Sorry for not providing a MWE. `uniquename=false` did the trick, but I'm still not sure why, since I don't have several entries with the same name "Li".

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp,citestyle=authoryear-comp,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=false,date=year,uniquename=false]{biblatex}

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't explain why you need `uniquename`  without an example document (with relevant `.bib` entries). Note that `biblatex`/Biber can't tell that "Donald Knuth" and "Donald E. Knuth" are the same person, so even if you only ever cite one "Knuth" you may get initials.

Comment: Anyway, I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of the `uniquename` question I linked above. If you want to know more details, you can ask a new question with MWE.