# Adding a citation makes the other citations change in weird way

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, lyx, natbib

This is really incomprehensibly strange. Adding separate citations makes the other citations look broken.

If I only have these two citations,

[image]

then the pdf result is perfectly normal.

[image]

But if I add either one of the two new citations,

[image]

then the pdf result shows "Autor" becomes "D. Autor"

Why does one citation affect other citations?

[image]

And I am using "Biblatex (natbib mode)" on Lyx. So far only this option works.

[image]

Comment: Another weird thing is why do the last two new citations show up only two names, not one name? Of course, I want one name followed by "et al." Why show up two names when there are three names?

Comment: Please post your code (including your bib file) as text, not an image.  It looks like one of your authors is "David Autor" and the other is "David H Autor", and BibTex is trying to distinguish the two.

Comment: Thank you so much. Removing "H" solved the problem. Though the problem was solved, I will share the bib file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xdBy5mR_eicv9UaZ5gui3AUhRVDPliWP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: But the other problem wasn't solved. Autor, Katz, and Krueger has 3 authors. Of course, I want to display "Autor et al." but it displays two authors "Autor, Katz, et al." How can I fix this?

Comment: This is the link to lyx file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mzOXvip_OpLCnnidNNdTWZ9pY4Q3W76q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You've tagged both 'biblatex' and 'natbib'. These packages are mutually incompatible. Which one do you use?

Comment: BTW, `journal={The Quarterly journal of economics},` is a real eye-sore. Please change it to `journal={The Quarterly Journal of Economics},`.  (Yes, I'm an economist too.)

Comment: @Mico  Thank you! And I added a screenshot showing what option I am using. Biblatex (natbib mode) is what I am using on Lyx.

Comment: You probably want the options `uniquename=false,` and `uniquelist=false,`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864. `biblatex` tries to avoid ambiguous names and name lists by adding initials or given names and adding more authors to make the list unique.