# Citation with bib latex

Tags: biblatex

I am using biblatex:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,maxnames=1,uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
```

when I write

```
for a detailed version see \cite{bernd1}
```

then I get

```
for a detailed version see Bernhard Spald 1990.
```

but I would like to have the following:

```
for a detailed version see [Spald 1990]
```

I don't know how to do it with biblatex? I don't find the right citing style...

Thank you in advance

Comment: use \parencite{bernd1}, you can then redefine it to use brackets instead of parentheses.

Comment: but I also don't want the full name, but only the surname and the year - is this possible with parencite?

Comment: sure, but you didn't provide an example that can be compiled, so I can't say why you don't get it.

Comment: what should the command be to get the desired style? then i can tell you if it works :) when I use parencite I get : (B. Spald 1990) but I want [Spald 1990]

Comment: Maybe the `author-year-icomp` style?

Comment: no the icomp style does not work either

Comment: In this case, add small, yet complete, example code reproducing the problem.

Comment: If you get unwanted given (first) names, then you probably have several authors with the same family (last) name (or several different versions of the same name, like `Donald Knuth` and `Donald E. Knuth`). In that case you may want to look at the `uniquename` option: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864

Comment: I know get the brackets, but I just want the surname and the year, but now I get for instance [Frank Rattay et. al 2001] instead of [Rattay et. al 2001] how can I force the system to do so?

Comment: Like I said in my last comment: That sounds like it would be caused by the `uniquename` functionality (I linked to an answer explaining how to turn it off, there is a also a reference to the relevant bit of the manual). Without a full example document that shows what you are doing and reproduces what you are seeing, that is of course guesswork, but it's the best I can do given the circumstances.