# Don't show initials in short version of author with same last name in biblatex windy city style

Tags: biblatex, windycity

Currently in the windycity style of biblatex, authors with the same last name will show initials when their short form is called. The *Chicago Manual of Style*, however, is unclear on whether this is needed when it can easily be determined which author is intended. I would like to remove this behaviour for my document. Ideally on a case by case basis, and otherwise for all entries. How can this best be done?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=windycity]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
    @book{book1,
        title = {First Book},
        author = {Author, The},
        location = {Place},
        publisher = {Publisher},
        date = {1980},
    }
    @book{book2,
        title = {Second Book},
        author = {Author, Another},
        location = {Place},
        publisher = {Publisher},
        date = {2020},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{biblio}
\begin{document}
    \cites{book1}{book2}
    
    \cites{book1}{book2}    
\end{document}
```

gives for the second citation:

> T. Author, *First Book*; A. Author, *Second Book*.

but the second citation to produce:

> Author, *First Book*; Author, *Second Book*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the `uniquename` feature, which tries to ensure unique label names. The feature can be turned off globally with the option `uniquename=false,`. See also [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864).

With newer versions of `biblatex`, it is also possible to give the `uniquename` option on a per-entry basis, which may or may not be more convenient for you. Note that turning off `uniquename` for one entry may affect other entries as well, since a disambiguation is no longer required if a particular name entry is ignored by the feature.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=windycity]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
  title     = {First Book},
  author    = {Author, The},
  location  = {Place},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date      = {1980},
}
@book{book2,
  title     = {Second Book},
  author    = {Author, Another},
  location  = {Place},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date      = {2020},
  options   = {uniquename=false},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
  \cites{book1}{book2}

  \cites{book1}{book2}
\end{document}
```

[image: Author, First Book; Author, Second Book.]

Comment: Oh that was an easy solution, thanks! I couldn't find the option because I was only looking in windycity rather than in biblatex as well