# Different initials in citation vs reference section

Tags: biblatex, citing, authoryear

I am having some problems with the "authoryear" citation in biblatex. In my bibliography there are two entries with the same author. While in one entry only the first name is mentioned, the second entry contains the abbreviation of the second first name. For consistency, I would like to keep this distinction. However, the problem arises that in the written text for these entries, instead of just last name and year, the abbreviation of the first name is also displayed. See the code below and a screenshot.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp, sortcites=false, maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1, maxbibnames=4, uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add the entries in the `.bib` file for these two references to your question? Also, what do you want the output to be? Just `R.` in both cases in the text, but the entries in the Reference section the same? Or you want only last names in the text and no initials?

Comment: I edited the title to what I think you are interested in, but feel free to change the title again if I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: You are seeing the effect of the `uniquename` feature. `biblatex` adds the initials to citations to make names unique (to avoid confusion about which Herrmann wrote which work), but `biblatex` does not know that the two Herrmanns are the same person. You probably just want to get rid of the complete feature entirely and add `uniquename=false,` to your `biblatex` options. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864.