# Problem with in-text citations and the sorting of the bibliography after name and year (both not uniform)

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I use this code block to declare the bibliography style of my article. The result for most of my in-text citations looks as expected (authoryear citation), however, some citations include the first names or more authors than needed (e.g., J. V. Smith, Williams, and Hall, 2020). I am using the `\citep{}`and `\textcite{}` commands.

Moreover, the sorting of my bibliography is not consistently in the style author year even though I am using `sorting=nyt`.

```
%%% Bibliography
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    bibencoding=utf8,
    bibwarn=false,
    isbn=false,
    url=true,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    giveninits=true,
    natbib=true,
    maxbibnames=99,
]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{family-given}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

Some example entries:

```
@article{vandenBroeke.2009,
 author = {{van den Broeke}, Michiel and Bamber, Jonathan and Ettema, Janneke and Rignot, Eric and Schrama, Ernst and {van de Berg}, Willem Jan and {van Meijgaard}, Erik and Velicogna, Isabella and Wouters, Bert},
 year = {2009},
 title = {Partitioning recent Greenland mass loss},
 pages = {984--986},
 pagination = {page},
 volume = {326},
 journaltitle = {Science (New York, N.Y.)},
 language = {eng},
 doi = {10.1126/science.1178176},
 number = {5955},
}


@article{vandenBroeke.2008,
 author = {{van den Broeke}, Michiel and Smeets, Paul and Ettema, Janneke and Munneke, Peter Kuipers},
 year = {2008},
 title = {Surface radiation balance in the ablation zone of the west Greenland ice sheet},
 keywords = {Greenland;observations;radiation balance},
 volume = {113},
 issn = {0148-0227},
 journaltitle = {Journal of Geophysical Research},
 shortjournal = {J. Geophys. Res.},
 doi = {10.1029/2007JD009283},
 number = {D13},
}

@article{vandenBroeke.2016,
 author = {{van den Broeke}, Michiel R. and Enderlin, Ellyn M. and Howat, Ian M. and {Kuipers Munneke}, Peter and No{\"e}l, Brice P. Y. and {van de Berg}, Willem Jan and {van Meijgaard}, Erik and Wouters, Bert},
 year = {2016},
 title = {On the recent contribution of the Greenland ice sheet to sea level change},
 pages = {1933--1946},
 pagination = {page},
 volume = {10},
 journaltitle = {The Cryosphere},
 doi = {10.5194/tc-10-1933-2016},
 number = {5},
 abstract = {}
}
```

I would like to have them sorted in the order after the last name of the first author and whenever multiple entries for the same author are available after the year. In case of my example:

1. van den Broeke 2008
2. van den Broeke 2009
3. van den Broeke 2016

Does anybody know how to solve these problems?

Comment: The sorting is impossible to debug without example entries and an explanation of which order would be expected.

Comment: The other observations are due to the `uniquename` and `uniquelist` options. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864 and the documentation for more in-depth explanation.

Comment: Your style setup is a bit odd. First you have `style=authoryear,` and then you overwrite just the bibliography style (but not the citation style) with `bibstyle=apa,`. It is APA style to set `uniquename` and `uniquelist` to the values you are currently seeing. But `biblatex-apa` is not supposed to be used together with a different citation style, it should be used as `style=apa,`. Note that `biblatex-apa` comes with its own sorting scheme and so setting `sorting=nyt, ` is counter-productive if you want APA style.

Comment: @moewe Thank you very much for your advice! Adding `uniquename` and `uniquelist` to my preamble solved the first issue.

Comment: @moewe I added some more detail to my sorting question above. However, after deleting `style=authoryear` and `sorting=nyt` the order is still not as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is correct APA style, which you requested with `biblatex-apa's` `style=apa,`.

If you do not want to follow proper APA style it is usually much better to start from one of the standard styles (e.g. `style=authoryear,` or `style=authoryear-comp,`) than to mess with `style=apa,`.

As already mentioned in the comments you are seeing the effect of the `uniquelist` and `uniquename` options. `biblatex` can try to avoid ambiguous "et al." truncations and can add given name initials to disambiguate different authors with the same family name (this includes cases where the same author is cited with slight variations in their name). See [Set limit to one author when using "et al." in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864) and [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864) for additional detail. In the MWE below both features are turned off (but that means that you are no longer APA compliant).

The standard sorting scheme takes all names that are visible in the bibliography into account when sorting the bibliography entries. So `vandenBroeke.2009` is sorted before `vandenBroeke.2008` because the second author of `vandenBroeke.2009` is Jonathan Bamber, who sorts before `vandenBroeke.2008`'s Paul Smeets. You can tell `biblatex` to ignore some names by playing around with the `minsortnames` and `maxsortnames` options (the rules are as follows: a list exceeding `maxsortnames` names is shortened to `minsortnames` names, so with `minsortnames=1, maxsortnames=3,` lists of four or more authors sort only by the first author).

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=apa,
  minsortnames=1, maxsortnames=3,
  uniquelist=false, uniquename=false
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{vandenBroeke.2009,
 author       = {van den Broeke, Michiel and Bamber, Jonathan
                 and Ettema, Janneke and Rignot, Eric and Schrama, Ernst
                 and van de Berg, Willem Jan and van Meijgaard, Erik
                 and Velicogna, Isabella and Wouters, Bert},
 year         = {2009},
 title        = {Partitioning Recent {Greenland} Mass Loss},
 pages        = {984--986},
 pagination   = {page},
 volume       = {326},
 journaltitle = {Science (New York, N.Y.)},
 language     = {eng},
 doi          = {10.1126/science.1178176},
 number       = {5955},
}
@article{vandenBroeke.2008,
 author       = {van den Broeke, Michiel and Smeets, Paul
                 and Ettema, Janneke and Kuipers Munneke, Peter},
 year         = {2008},
 title        = {Surface Radiation Balance in the Ablation Zone
                 of the West {Greenland} Ice Sheet},
 keywords     = {Greenland;observations;radiation balance},
 volume       = {113},
 issn         = {0148-0227},
 journaltitle = {Journal of Geophysical Research},
 shortjournal = {J. Geophys. Res.},
 doi          = {10.1029/2007JD009283},
 number       = {D13},
}
@article{vandenBroeke.2016,
 author       = {van den Broeke, Michiel R. and Enderlin, Ellyn M.
                 and Howat, Ian M. and Kuipers Munneke, Peter
                 and Noël, Brice P. Y. and van de Berg, Willem Jan
                 and van Meijgaard, Erik and Wouters, Bert},
 year         = {2016},
 title        = {On the Recent Contribution of the
                 {Greenland} Ice Sheet to Sea Level Change},
 pages        = {1933--1946},
 pagination   = {page},
 volume       = {10},
 journaltitle = {The Cryosphere},
 doi          = {10.5194/tc-10-1933-2016},
 number       = {5},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,vandenBroeke.2009,vandenBroeke.2008,vandenBroeke.2016}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E., & Ryde, U. (1998).//van den Broeke, M., Smeets, P., Ettema, J., & Munneke, P. K. (2008).//van den Broeke, M., Bamber, J., Ettema, J., Rignot, E., Schrama, E., van de Berg, W. J., van Meijgaard, E., Velicogna, I., & Wouters, B.//van den Broeke, M. R., Enderlin, E. M., Howat, I. M., Kuipers Munneke, P., Noël, B. P. Y., van de Berg, W. J., van Meijgaard, E., & Wouters, B.]

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed answer! This solved all of the problems mentioned!