# BibLaTeX Citation Showing Letter of First Name of Author

Tags: biblatex

I have used LaTeX for some time now for writing academic articles, but encountered an error which I haven't seen before. When citing an article in-text, the first letter of the name of the author is also shown.

This is an example of a LaTeX line where the problem occurs:

```
\textcite{YuFangZhuMa2019} develop an exact polynomial-time algorithm with the use of the Karush-Kun-Tucker conditions.
```

The result is

> Q. Yu et al. (2019) develop an exact polynomial-time algorithm with the use of the Karush-Kun-Tucker conditions.

[image: Q. Yu et al. (2019)]

In the preamble I've used the `biblatex` package as follows:

```
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

And the corresponding bibliography entry is as follows:

```
@article{YuFangZhuMa2019,
author = {Yu, Q. and Fang, F. and Zhu, N. and Ma, S.},
title = {{A Matheuristic Approach to the Orienteering Problem with Service Time Dependent Profits}},
journal = {European Journal of Operations Research},
year = 2019,
volume = 273,
number = 2,
pages = {488-503},
doi = {10.1016/j.ejor.2018.08.007}
}
```

As with all other citations, it should just show as "Yu et al. (2019)", and not as "Q. Yu et al. (2019). As far as I can tell, this problem only occurs for articles in which the last name of the first author is too short, i.e. consists of only two letters. If I change the last name of the first author to "Yun", the citation shows correctly. A quick and easy solution would be to remove the first name letter in the bibliography entry, but this results in an inconsistency in bibliography representation, with some authors having a first name and some having none. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This is expected if you have several works where different Yus are the first author. See https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/citing-authors-same-surname. (See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864)

Comment: I should say that this is expected specifically in APA style. If you don't want APA style, you may want to pick a different style, for example the vanilla `style=authoryear,`.

Answer (score 3):

As the [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134535/biblatex-authoryear-style-in-text-citations-display-first-name-initials-for-ce) linked by moewe shows, you could add `uniquename=false` to the options of `biblatex:`

```
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
```

[image]

will become

[image]

with this code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{YuFangZhuMa2019,
author = {Yu, Q. and Fang, F. and Zhu, N. and Ma, S.},
title = {{A Matheuristic Approach to the Orienteering Problem with Service Time Dependent Profits}},
journal = {European Journal of Operations Research},
year = 2019,
volume = 273,
number = 2,
pages = {488-503},
doi = {10.1016/j.ejor.2018.08.007}
}

@article{YuFangZhuMa2020,
author = {Yu, F. and Fang, F. and Zhu, N. and Ma, S.},
title = {{A refutation.}},
journal = {European Journal of Operations Research},
year = 2020,
volume = 274,
number = 2,
pages = {488-503},
doi = {10.1016/j.ejor.2018.08.007}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{YuFangZhuMa2019} develop an exact polynomial-time algorithm with the use of the Karush-Kun-Tucker conditions. 

\textcite{YuFangZhuMa2020} say this is codswallop.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```