# Biblatex: Inconsistent name format of citations and bibliography

Tags: biblatex, citing, miktex, biber

Here is my MWE, which shows that citations appear in a (seemingly) inconsistent way:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{csquotes} % Seems to be needed by biblatex
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nyvt,style=authoryear,natbib,doi=false,eprint=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}% This ensures the correct ordering of the first name and the last name in the bibliography
\bibliography{Biblio} % Overleaf uses/recommends to use \addbibresource{Biblio.bib} instead of \bibliography.


% for having a self-contained example:
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Biblio.bib}

@ARTICLE{BlandfordZnajek,
       author = {{Blandford}, R.~D. and {Znajek}, R.~L.},
        title = "{Electromagnetic extraction of energy from Kerr black holes.}",
      journal = {\mnras},
     keywords = {Black Holes (Astronomy), Electromagnetic Fields, Energy Sources, Rotating Matter, Active Galactic Nuclei, Astrophysics, Electron-Positron Pairs, Pair Production, Astrophysics},
         year = 1977,
        month = may,
       volume = {179},
        pages = {433-456},
          doi = {10.1093/mnras/179.3.433},
       url = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1977MNRAS.179..433B},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{1992ApJ...385L...1H,
       author = {{Hartman}, R.~C. and {Bertsch}, D.~L. and {Fichtel}, C.~E. and
         {Hunter}, S.~D. and {Kanbach}, G. and {Kniffen}, D.~A. and
         {Kwok}, P.~W. and {Lin}, Y.~C. and {Mattox}, J.~R. and {Mayer-Hasselwand
        er}, H.~A. and {Michelson}, P.~F. and {von Montigny}, C. and
         {Nel}, H.~I. and {Nolan}, P.~L. and {Pinkau}, K. and {Rothermel}, H. and
         {Schneid}, E. and {Sommer}, M. and {Sreekumar}, P. and
         {Thompson}, D.~J.},
        title = "{Detection of High-Energy Gamma Radiation from Quasar 3C 279 by the EGRET Telescope on the Compton Gamma Ray Observatory}",
      journal = {\apjl},
     keywords = {Gamma Ray Spectra, Quasars, Active Galactic Nuclei, Gamma Ray Observatory, Telescopes, Space Radiation, GALAXIES: QUASARS: INDIVIDUAL ALPHANUMERIC: 3C 279, GAMMA RAYS: OBSERVATIONS},
         year = 1992,
        month = jan,
       volume = {385},
        pages = {L1},
          doi = {10.1086/186263},
       url = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1992ApJ...385L...1H},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{BlandfordLevinson,
       author = {{Blandford}, R.~D. and {Levinson}, A.},
        title = "{Pair Cascades in Extragalactic Jets. I. Gamma Rays}",
      journal = {\apj},
     keywords = {Active Galactic Nuclei, Astronomical Models, Electron Photon Cascades, Gamma Rays, Magnetohydrodynamic Waves, Radio Jets (Astronomy), Relativistic Effects, Compton Effect, Gamma Ray Observatory, Astrophysics, ACCELERATION OF PARTICLES, GALAXIES: ACTIVE, GALAXIES: JETS, MAGNETOHYDRODYNAMICS: MHD, RADIATION MECHANISMS: NONTHERMAL},
         year = 1995,
        month = mar,
       volume = {441},
        pages = {79},
          doi = {10.1086/175338},
       url = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1995ApJ...441...79B},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{1995MNRAS.277..681M,
       author = {{Marcowith}, A. and {Henri}, G. and {Pelletier}, G.},
        title = "{Gamma-ray emission of blazars by a relativistic electron-positron beam}",
      journal = {\mnras},
     keywords = {RADIATION MECHANISMS: NONTHERMAL, GALAXIES: ACTIVE, GALAXIES: JETS},
         year = 1995,
        month = nov,
       volume = {277},
       number = {2},
        pages = {681-699},
          doi = {10.1093/mnras/277.2.681},
       url = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1995MNRAS.277..681M},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{2002ApJ...564...86B,
       author = {{B{\"o}ttcher}, M. and {Dermer}, C.~D.},
        title = "{An Evolutionary Scenario for Blazar Unification}",
      journal = {\apj},
     keywords = {Galaxies: Active, Gamma Rays: Theory, Astrophysics},
         year = 2002,
        month = jan,
       volume = {564},
       number = {1},
        pages = {86-91},
          doi = {10.1086/324134},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {astro-ph/0106395},
 primaryClass = {astro-ph},
       url = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2002ApJ...564...86B},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{2007CSE.....9...90H,
       author = {{Hunter}, John D.},
        title = "{Matplotlib: A 2D Graphics Environment}",
      journal = {Computing in Science and Engineering},
     keywords = {Python, Scripting languages, Application development, Scientific programming},
         year = 2007,
        month = may,
       volume = {9},
       number = {3},
        pages = {90-95},
          doi = {10.1109/MCSE.2007.55},
       url = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2007CSE.....9...90H},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{2010ApJ...716...30A,
       author = {{Abdo}, A.~A. and {Ackermann}, M. and {Agudo}, I. and {Ajello}, M. and {Aller}, H.~D. and {Aller}, M.~F. and {Angelakis}, E. and {Arkharov}, A.~A. and {Axelsson}, M. and {Bach}, U. and {Baldini}, L. and {Ballet}, J. and {Barbiellini}, G. and {Bastieri}, D. and {Baughman}, B.~M. and {Bechtol}, K. and {Bellazzini}, R. and {Benitez}, E. and {Berdyugin}, A. and {Berenji}, B. and {Blandford}, R.~D. and {Bloom}, E.~D. and {Boettcher}, M. and {Bonamente}, E. and {Borgland}, A.~W. and {Bregeon}, J. and {Brez}, A. and {Brigida}, M. and {Bruel}, P. and {Burnett}, T.~H. and {Burrows}, D. and {Buson}, S. and {Caliandro}, G.~A. and {Calzoletti}, L. and {Cameron}, R.~A. and {Capalbi}, M. and {Caraveo}, P.~A. and {Carosati}, D. and {Casandjian}, J.~M. and {Cavazzuti}, E. and {Cecchi}, C. and {{\c{C}}elik}, {\"O}. and {Charles}, E. and {Chaty}, S. and {Chekhtman}, A. and {Chen}, W.~P. and {Chiang}, J. and {Chincarini}, G. and {Ciprini}, S. and {Claus}, R. and {Cohen-Tanugi}, J. and {Colafrancesco}, S. and {Cominsky}, L.~R. and {Conrad}, J. and {Costamante}, L. and {Cutini}, S. and {D'ammando}, F. and {Deitrick}, R. and {D'Elia}, V. and {Dermer}, C.~D. and {de Angelis}, A. and {de Palma}, F. and {Digel}, S.~W. and {Donnarumma}, I. and {Silva}, E. do Couto e. and {Drell}, P.~S. and {Dubois}, R. and {Dultzin}, D. and {Dumora}, D. and {Falcone}, A. and {Farnier}, C. and {Favuzzi}, C. and {Fegan}, S.~J. and {Focke}, W.~B. and {Forn{\'e}}, E. and {Fortin}, P. and {Frailis}, M. and {Fuhrmann}, L. and {Fukazawa}, Y. and {Funk}, S. and {Fusco}, P. and {G{\'o}mez}, J.~L. and {Gargano}, F. and {Gasparrini}, D. and {Gehrels}, N. and {Germani}, S. and {Giebels}, B. and {Giglietto}, N. and {Giommi}, P. and {Giordano}, F. and {Giuliani}, A. and {Glanzman}, T. and {Godfrey}, G. and {Grenier}, I.~A. and {Gronwall}, C. and {Grove}, J.~E. and {Guillemot}, L. and {Guiriec}, S. and {Gurwell}, M.~A. and {Hadasch}, D. and {Hanabata}, Y. and {Harding}, A.~K. and {Hayashida}, M. and {Hays}, E. and {Healey}, S.~E. and {Heidt}, J. and {Hiriart}, D. and {Horan}, D. and {Hoversten}, E.~A. and {Hughes}, R.~E. and {Itoh}, R. and {Jackson}, M.~S. and {J{\'o}hannesson}, G. and {Johnson}, A.~S. and {Johnson}, W.~N. and {Jorstad}, S.~G. and {Kadler}, M. and {Kamae}, T. and {Katagiri}, H. and {Kataoka}, J. and {Kawai}, N. and {Kennea}, J. and {Kerr}, M. and {Kimeridze}, G. and {Kn{\"o}dlseder}, J. and {Kocian}, M.~L. and {Kopatskaya}, E.~N. and {Koptelova}, E. and {Konstantinova}, T.~S. and {Kovalev}, Y.~Y. and {Kovalev}, Yu. A. and {Kurtanidze}, O.~M. and {Kuss}, M. and {Lande}, J. and {Larionov}, V.~M. and {Latronico}, L. and {Leto}, P. and {Lindfors}, E. and {Longo}, F. and {Loparco}, F. and {Lott}, B. and {Lovellette}, M.~N. and {Lubrano}, P. and {Madejski}, G.~M. and {Makeev}, A. and {Marchegiani}, P. and {Marscher}, A.~P. and {Marshall}, F. and {Max-Moerbeck}, W. and {Mazziotta}, M.~N. and {McConville}, W. and {McEnery}, J.~E. and {Meurer}, C. and {Michelson}, P.~F. and {Mitthumsiri}, W. and {Mizuno}, T. and {Moiseev}, A.~A. and {Monte}, C. and {Monzani}, M.~E. and {Morselli}, A. and {Moskalenko}, I.~V. and {Murgia}, S. and {Nestoras}, I. and {Nilsson}, K. and {Nizhelsky}, N.~A. and {Nolan}, P.~L. and {Norris}, J.~P. and {Nuss}, E. and {Ohsugi}, T. and {Ojha}, R. and {Omodei}, N. and {Orlando}, E. and {Ormes}, J.~F. and {Osborne}, J. and {Ozaki}, M. and {Pacciani}, L. and {Padovani}, P. and {Pagani}, C. and {Page}, K. and {Paneque}, D. and {Panetta}, J.~H. and {Parent}, D. and {Pasanen}, M. and {Pavlidou}, V. and {Pelassa}, V. and {Pepe}, M. and {Perri}, M. and {Pesce-Rollins}, M. and {Piranomonte}, S. and {Piron}, F. and {Pittori}, C. and {Porter}, T.~A. and {Puccetti}, S. and {Rahoui}, F. and {Rain{\`o}}, S. and {Raiteri}, C. and {Rando}, R. and {Razzano}, M. and {Reimer}, A. and {Reimer}, O. and {Reposeur}, T. and {Richards}, J.~L. and {Ritz}, S. and {Rochester}, L.~S. and {Rodriguez}, A.~Y. and {Romani}, R.~W. and {Ros}, J.~A. and {Roth}, M. and {Roustazadeh}, P. and {Ryde}, F. and {Sadrozinski}, H.~F. -W. and {Sadun}, A. and {Sanchez}, D. and {Sander}, A. and {Saz Parkinson}, P.~M. and {Scargle}, J.~D. and {Sellerholm}, A. and {Sgr{\`o}}, C. and {Shaw}, M.~S. and {Sigua}, L.~A. and {Siskind}, E.~J. and {Smith}, D.~A. and {Smith}, P.~D. and {Spandre}, G. and {Spinelli}, P. and {Starck}, J. -L. and {Stevenson}, M. and {Stratta}, G. and {Strickman}, M.~S. and {Suson}, D.~J. and {Tajima}, H. and {Takahashi}, H. and {Takahashi}, T. and {Takalo}, L.~O. and {Tanaka}, T. and {Thayer}, J.~B. and {Thayer}, J.~G. and {Thompson}, D.~J. and {Tibaldo}, L. and {Torres}, D.~F. and {Tosti}, G. and {Tramacere}, A. and {Uchiyama}, Y. and {Usher}, T.~L. and {Vasileiou}, V. and {Verrecchia}, F. and {Vilchez}, N. and {Villata}, M. and {Vitale}, V. and {Waite}, A.~P. and {Wang}, P. and {Winer}, B.~L. and {Wood}, K.~S. and {Ylinen}, T. and {Zensus}, J.~A. and {Zhekanis}, G.~V. and {Ziegler}, M.},
        title = "{The Spectral Energy Distribution of Fermi Bright Blazars}",
      journal = {\apj},
     keywords = {BL Lacertae objects: general, galaxies: active, gamma rays: galaxies, quasars: general, radiation mechanisms: non-thermal, Astrophysics - Cosmology and Nongalactic Astrophysics},
         year = 2010,
        month = jun,
       volume = {716},
       number = {1},
        pages = {30-70},
          doi = {10.1088/0004-637X/716/1/30},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {0912.2040},
 primaryClass = {astro-ph.CO},
       url = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010ApJ...716...30A},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{2010ApJ...724.1517B,
       author = {{Barkov}, Maxim V. and {Aharonian}, Felix A. and
         {Bosch-Ramon}, Valent{\'\i}},
        title = "{Gamma-ray Flares from Red Giant/Jet Interactions in Active Galactic Nuclei}",
      journal = {\apj},
     keywords = {acceleration of particles, galaxies: jets, gamma rays: galaxies, hydrodynamics, radiation mechanisms: non-thermal, stars: flare, Astrophysics - High Energy Astrophysical Phenomena},
         year = 2010,
        month = dec,
       volume = {724},
       number = {2},
        pages = {1517-1523},
          doi = {10.1088/0004-637X/724/2/1517},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {1005.5252},
 primaryClass = {astro-ph.HE},
       url = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010ApJ...724.1517B},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{2011ApJ...730..123L,
       author = {{Levinson}, Amir and {Rieger}, Frank},
        title = "{Variable TeV Emission as a Manifestation of Jet Formation in M87?}",
      journal = {\apj},
     keywords = {galaxies: individual: M87, gamma rays: galaxies, radiation mechanisms: non-thermal, Astrophysics - High Energy Astrophysical Phenomena},
         year = 2011,
        month = apr,
       volume = {730},
       number = {2},
          eid = {123},
        pages = {123},
          doi = {10.1088/0004-637X/730/2/123},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {1011.5319},
 primaryClass = {astro-ph.HE},
       url = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011ApJ...730..123L},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{ReferenceVariability4,
   author = {{Aleksi{\'c}}, J. and {Ansoldi}, S. and {Antonelli}, L.~A. and 
    {Antoranz}, P. and {Babic}, A. and {Bangale}, P. and {Barrio}, J.~A. and 
    {Gonz{\'a}lez}, J.~B. and {Bednarek}, W. and {Bernardini}, E. and 
    {Biasuzzi}, B. and {Biland}, A. and {Blanch}, O. and {Bonnefoy}, S. and 
    {Bonnoli}, G. and {Borracci}, F. and {Bretz}, T. and {Carmona}, E. and 
    {Carosi}, A. and {Colin}, P. and {Colombo}, E. and {Contreras}, J.~L. and 
    {Cortina}, J. and {Covino}, S. and {Da Vela}, P. and {Dazzi}, F. and 
    {De Angelis}, A. and {De Caneva}, G. and {De Lotto}, B. and 
    {Wilhelmi}, E.~d.~O. and {Mendez}, C.~D. and {Prester}, D.~D. and 
    {Dorner}, D. and {Doro}, M. and {Einecke}, S. and {Eisenacher}, D. and 
    {Elsaesser}, D. and {Fonseca}, M.~V. and {Font}, L. and {Frantzen}, K. and 
    {Fruck}, C. and {Galindo}, D. and {L{\'o}pez}, R.~J.~G. and 
    {Garczarczyk}, M. and {Terrats}, D.~G. and {Gaug}, M. and {Godinovi{\'c}}, N. and 
    {Mu{\~n}oz}, A.~G. and {Gozzini}, S.~R. and {Hadasch}, D. and 
    {Hanabata}, Y. and {Hayashida}, M. and {Herrera}, J. and {Hildebrand}, D. and 
    {Hose}, J. and {Hrupec}, D. and {Idec}, W. and {Kadenius}, V. and 
    {Kellermann}, H. and {Kodani}, K. and {Konno}, Y. and {Krause}, J. and 
    {Kubo}, H. and {Kushida}, J. and {La Barbera}, A. and {Lelas}, D. and 
    {Lewandowska}, N. and {Lindfors}, E. and {Lombardi}, S. and 
    {Longo}, F. and {L{\'o}pez}, M. and {L{\'o}pez-Coto}, R. and 
    {L{\'o}pez-Oramas}, A. and {Lorenz}, E. and {Lozano}, I. and 
    {Makariev}, M. and {Mallot}, K. and {Maneva}, G. and {Mankuzhiyil}, N. and 
    {Mannheim}, K. and {Maraschi}, L. and {Marcote}, B. and {Mariotti}, M. and 
    {Mart{\'{\i}}nez}, M. and {Mazin}, D. and {Menzel}, U. and {Miranda}, J.~M. and 
    {Mirzoyan}, R. and {Moralejo}, A. and {Munar-Adrover}, P. and 
    {Nakajima}, D. and {Niedzwiecki}, A. and {Nilsson}, K. and {Nishijima}, K. and 
    {Noda}, K. and {Orito}, R. and {Overkemping}, A. and {Paiano}, S. and 
    {Palatiello}, M. and {Paneque}, D. and {Paoletti}, R. and {Paredes}, J.~M. and 
    {Paredes-Fortuny}, X. and {Persic}, M. and {Poutanen}, J. and 
    {Moroni}, P.~G.~P. and {Prandini}, E. and {Puljak}, I. and {Reinthal}, R. and 
    {Rhode}, W. and {Rib{\'o}}, M. and {Rico}, J. and {Garcia}, J.~R. and 
    {R{\"u}gamer}, S. and {Saito}, T. and {Saito}, K. and {Satalecka}, K. and 
    {Scalzotto}, V. and {Scapin}, V. and {Schultz}, C. and {Schweizer}, T. and 
    {Shore}, S.~N. and {Sillanp{\"a}{\"a}}, A. and {Sitarek}, J. and 
    {Snidaric}, I. and {Sobczynska}, D. and {Spanier}, F. and {Stamatescu}, V. and 
    {Stamerra}, A. and {Steinbring}, T. and {Storz}, J. and {Strzys}, M. and 
    {Takalo}, L. and {Takami}, H. and {Tavecchio}, F. and {Temnikov}, P. and 
    {Terzi{\'c}}, T. and {Tescaro}, D. and {Teshima}, M. and {Thaele}, J. and 
    {Tibolla}, O. and {Torres}, D.~F. and {Toyama}, T. and {Treves}, A. and 
    {Uellenbeck}, M. and {Vogler}, P. and {Zanin}, R. and {Kadler}, M. and 
    {Schulz}, R. and {Ros}, E. and {Bach}, U. and {Krau{\ss}}, F. and 
    {Wilms}, J.},
    title = "{Black hole lightning due to particle acceleration at subhorizon scales}",
  journal = {Science},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {1412.4936},
 primaryClass = "astro-ph.HE",
     year = 2014,
    month = nov,
   volume = 346,
    pages = {1080-1084},
      doi = {10.1126/science.1256183},
   url = {http://ads.ari.uni-heidelberg.de/abs/2014Sci...346.1080A},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{2014ApJ...782...82D,
       author = {{Dermer}, Charles D. and {Cerruti}, Matteo and {Lott}, Benoit and {Boisson}, Catherine and {Zech}, Andreas},
        title = "{Equipartition Gamma-Ray Blazars and the Location of the Gamma-Ray Emission Site in 3C 279}",
      journal = {\apj},
     keywords = {galaxies: jets, gamma rays: general, radiation mechanisms: non-thermal, Astrophysics - High Energy Astrophysical Phenomena},
         year = 2014,
        month = feb,
       volume = {782},
       number = {2},
          eid = {82},
        pages = {82},
          doi = {10.1088/0004-637X/782/2/82},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {1304.6680},
 primaryClass = {astro-ph.HE},
       url = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014ApJ...782...82D},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{AharonianVariability,
       author = {{Aharonian}, F.~A. and {Barkov}, M.~V. and {Khangulyan}, D.},
        title = "{Scenarios for Ultrafast Gamma-Ray Variability in AGN}",
      journal = {\apj},
     keywords = {galaxies: jets, galaxies: nuclei, gamma rays: galaxies, radiation mechanisms:nonthermal, Astrophysics - High Energy Astrophysical Phenomena},
         year = 2017,
        month = may,
       volume = {841},
       number = {1},
          eid = {61},
        pages = {61},
          doi = {10.3847/1538-4357/aa7049},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {1704.08148},
 primaryClass = {astro-ph.HE},
       url = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017ApJ...841...61A},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{2017AIPC.1792b0008R,
       author = {{Rieger}, Frank M.},
        title = "{Gamma-rays from non-blazar AGN}",
     keywords = {Astrophysics - High Energy Astrophysical Phenomena},
    booktitle = {6th International Symposium on High Energy Gamma-Ray Astronomy},
         year = 2017,
       series = {American Institute of Physics Conference Series},
       volume = {1792},
        month = jan,
          eid = {020008},
        pages = {020008},
          doi = {10.1063/1.4968893},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {1611.02986},
 primaryClass = {astro-ph.HE},
       url = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017AIPC.1792b0008R},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{2020NatCo..11.4176S,
       author = {{Shukla}, A. and {Mannheim}, K.},
        title = "{Gamma-ray flares from relativistic magnetic reconnection in the jet of the quasar 3C 279}",
      journal = {Nature Communications},
         year = 2020,
        month = aug,
       volume = {11},
          eid = {4176},
        pages = {4176},
          doi = {10.1038/s41467-020-17912-z},
       url = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2020NatCo..11.4176S},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{2021ApJ...917...32W,
       author = {{Wendel}, Christoph and {Shukla}, Amit and {Mannheim}, Karl},
        title = "{Pair Cascades at the Edge of the Broad-line Region Shaping the Gamma-Ray Spectrum of 3C 279}",
      journal = {\apj},
     keywords = {Active galaxies, Active galactic nuclei, Blazars, Flat-spectrum radio quasars, Quasars, Supermassive black holes, Gamma-ray sources, Gamma-rays, Non-thermal radiation sources, Relativistic jets, Radiative processes, 17, 16, 164, 2163, 1319, 1663, 633, 637, 1119, 1390, 2055, Astrophysics - High Energy Astrophysical Phenomena},
         year = 2021,
        month = aug,
       volume = {917},
       number = {1},
          eid = {32},
        pages = {32},
          doi = {10.3847/1538-4357/ac0a6e},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {2108.01028},
 primaryClass = {astro-ph.HE},
       url = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2021ApJ...917...32W},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

\end{filecontents}


% The following definitions make the ADS-bibtex snippets usable.
\newcommand*\apj{ApJ}
\newcommand*\apjl{ApJ}
\let\apjlett\apjl
\newcommand*\mnras{MNRAS}


\begin{document}

\,\\
One author:\\
That's how it should be: \citet{2007CSE.....9...90H}\\
Here, the initials of the first name are written: \citet{2017AIPC.1792b0008R}\\
Even though, in both cases, the appearance of the name in the bibliography is equal.\\
\\
Two authors:\\
That's how it should be: \citet{BlandfordZnajek}\\
Here, the first author's last name is given, while the second author's initial of the first name is also given: \citet{BlandfordLevinson}\\
\citet{2002ApJ...564...86B}\\
Here, both author's initials of the first name are also given: \citet{2020NatCo..11.4176S}\\
Here, the first author's full first name is given, while the second author's initial of the first name is given: \citet{2011ApJ...730..123L}\\
\\
Three authors:\\
That's how it should be: \citet{1995MNRAS.277..681M}\\
Here, the first author's first name is omitted while the second and third author's full first names are given: \citet{2021ApJ...917...32W}\\
Here, the third author's first name is omitted while the second and third author's first names are given and the second names are given as initials: \citet{2010ApJ...724.1517B}\\
Here, the third author's first name is omitted while the second and third author's first and second names are given as initials: \citet{AharonianVariability}\\
\\
Many authors:\\
That's how it should be: \citet{1992ApJ...385L...1H}\\
Here, the first author's full first name is given and the second name as initial: \citet{2014ApJ...782...82D}\\
Here, sometimes it occurs (I swear that it really happens if the Biblio.bib file is longer, but I cannot reproduce it anymore) that three last names are given and then et al.: \citet{2010ApJ...716...30A}\\
Here, sometimes it occurs (I swear that it really happens if the Biblio.bib file is longer, but I cannot reproduce it anymore) that seven last names are given and then et al.: \citet{ReferenceVariability4}\\

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The bibtex snippets are copy&pasted from [ADS](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/classic-form).

I am using TeXnic Centre 2.02 with MikTeX 2.9.
Here is the result:
[image: First page with the citations]
[image: Second page with first part of bibliography]
[image: Third page with second part of bibliography]

My questions are:

1. Why are the citation formats so different? I don't recognise a pattern when they appear in which format. How can I achieve that only family names (and no given names or initials) are printed in the citations with \citet and \citep?
2. How can I achieve (without modifying every bibtex entry) that in the Bibliography, every name is in the format `family-name, initials-of-given-name` like for example `Kirk, J. T.`

I have already tried the option `giveninits=false`, but it has no effect. I have also tried (just for curiosity) the option `maxcitenames=1`. It works at some places, but it does not work at other places.

I know the answer is "it's no inconsistency, it is a feature". But then please tell me how this feature can usefully be applied.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You will want to look at the options `uniquename` and `uniquelist` to stop `biblatex` from adding name initials or more names than `maxcitenames`/you expect (set both options to `false`). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864.

Comment: For 2 you want `giveninits=true,` and not `giveninits=false,` (i.e. you want `biblatex` to produce initials and not the full name), so you set the option to `true`.

Comment: Hi, nice to be here.

@moewe: Thanks, perfectly solved!

Comment: `giveninits=true` solved problem 2.
`uniquename=false` solved problem 1.

The question tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864 also showed me that `biblatex` will not truncate names of citations if doing so would cause ambiguous citations. This was sometimes the case, when I had more references in my file and it led to some citations having five or seven names. To force biblatex to truncate and to write 2014a and 2014b instead, `uniquelist=false` is ideal.

Once again big thanks, @moewe