biblatex with backend biber shows all names as well as et al.,
I use these parameters to load the biblatex addon.
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}

then i change some rules to define my own citation style like
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % Deine Bibliographie-Datei einbinden
% Anpassung der Zitierregeln
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\space\&\space} % Um zwischen den Namen der Autoren "&" zu haben
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\space\&\space}
% Mehr als 2 Autoren als "et al."
\renewcommand*{\finalandcomma}{}
\renewcommand*{\finalandsemicolon}{\addsemicolon}
\renewcommand*{\finalandcomma}{\addcomma}
%\renewcommand*{\andothersdelim}{\addcomma\space et\addspace al.}
% Anpassung für "et al." auch im Text
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},}
% Klammerart für "et al."-Abkürzung
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}

in my bibliography i have the entries like:
@article{kemski2012,
  author  = {Kemski, J. and Klingel, R. and Siehl, A. and Neznal, A. and Matolin, M.},
  title   = {Sachstandsbericht "Radonmessungen in der Bodenluft - Einflussfaktoren, Messverfahren, Bewertung"},
  journal = {Salzgitter BfS-RESFOR},
  volume  = {12},
  number  = {2},
  year    = {2012},
  pages   = {63}
}

then i use ...dem Austritt des Gases in die Atmosphäre \parencite{kemski2012}. and i get:

dem Austritt des Gases in die Atmosphäre (Kemski & Klingel & Siehl &
A. Neznal et al., 2012).

But i want this:

dem Austritt des Gases in die Atmosphäre (Kemski et al., 2012).

May you can help me to solve this problem :)
SOLVED by moewe:
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxcitenames=2, uniquelist=false]{biblatex}


I can't reproduce the problem. When I add \documentclass{article} at the start of your code and `\begin{document}
dem Austritt des Gases in die Atmosphäre \parencite{kemski2012}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}` at the end then I get (Kemski et al., 2012) in the text as expected. Maybe you use a different documentclass that does its own settings? Please add the missing details to your code and make sure that the code that you provide, without changes, reproduces the problem that you describe.

We would need to see a fully compilable example document that we can run on our machines without modification and that reproduces your issue in order to investigate this properly. Usually "too many names" or "unnecessary given name initials" are due to the uniquelist and uniquename features: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864

@moewe youre right with \usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxcitenames=2, uniquelist=false]{biblatex} it is working. Thanks a lot!
