# Numeric bibliography with author year title order

Tags: biblatex

The supervisor of my thesis asked me to have a specific style in my bibliography. For example, an entry like the following

```
@article{cybenko,
         title={Approximation by superpositions of a sigmoidal function},
         author={Cybenko, George},
         journal={Mathematics of Control, Signals and Systems},
         volume={2},
         number={4},
         pages={303--314},
         year={1989},
         publisher={Springer}
}
```

Should look a like this

> [1] Cybenko, G. (1989) Approximation by superpositions of a sigmoidal function. *Mathematics of Control Signals and Systems 2*, 303–314.

Does anyone know if there is a style in `biblatex` that is equivalent to his demands or if I should create my own style?

Comment: Yes, it helps but I would also like for the first name to be abbreviated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following my answer in [Combining style numeric with style authoryear in BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314014/35864) as well as the modifications explained in [Suppress "In:" biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864), [biblatex: Abbreviated author names?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21974/35864), [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864) and a few other small changes we can come up with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    %sorting=none,
    citestyle=numeric,
    bibstyle=authoryear,
    giveninits=true,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\input{numeric.bbx}
\makeatother

% get back the convenient alias
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

% only for biblatex >= 3.12
% uncomment the lines if they produce undefined control sequence errors
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname}

% for biblatex >= 3.4, otherwise redefine \labelnamepunct
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}{#1}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,wilde,geer,worman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Numeric bibliography with author-year-title order, e.g. "Sigfridsson, E. and Ryde, U. (1998) Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P."]

Comment: Thank you, I could never have done it by myself