# Insert period in author's initials

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the codes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%
\usepackage[natbib,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Adesnik2012,
author = {Adesnik, H and Bruns, W and Taniguchi, H and Huang, Z J and Scanziani, M},
doi = {101038/nature11526},
issn = {1476-4687},
journal = {Nature},
month = 10,
number = {7419},
pages = {226--31},
pmid = {23060193},
publisher = {Nature Publishing Group},
title = {{A neural circuit for spatial summation in visual cortex}},
volume = {490},
year = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output is:

[image]

I need to insert period after initials, i.e., the output should be as:

`Adesnik, H, W. Bruns, H. Taniguchi, Z. J. Huang, and M. Scanziani. 2012....`

Comment: Don't you get an error because of an option clash while loading the packages?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Sorry, I didn't get nothing error, it's working, actually `biblatex.sty` doesn't have the option `authordate`, so only I used `biblatex-chicago` too, please excuse if any thing wrong in my tagging

Comment: Please be careful here.  There are legitimately individuals whose names consist of only a single letter.  The mathematician R H Bing was such a person.  On legal documents, it would have been required to enter his name as R(only) H(only) Bing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Much thanks for advise, actually I'm not good in English, that's the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot load the `biblatex` package after `biblatex-chicago`. `biblatex-chicago` will automatically load the `biblatex` package and it uses different options to do this. If you try to load `biblatex` again with different options, you will get an error because of the option clash.

That being said, you can use the `giveninits=true` option to show only the initials (including a period) of the first names:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber,giveninits=true]{biblatex-chicago}%
%\usepackage[natbib,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Adesnik2012,
author = {Adesnik, H and Bruns, W and Taniguchi, H and Huang, Z J and Scanziani, M},
doi = {101038/nature11526},
issn = {1476-4687},
journal = {Nature},
month = 10,
number = {7419},
pages = {226--31},
pmid = {23060193},
publisher = {Nature Publishing Group},
title = {{A neural circuit for spatial summation in visual cortex}},
volume = {490},
year = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `giveninits=true` should be preferred https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21977

Comment: @DaiBowen Thanks! Fixed

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks a lot, it's working perfectly