# How to modify `unsrt.bst` file to generate concise and readable Jounal of Applied Phyisics(JAP) style .bbl file?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am going to submit an article to Journal Of Applied Physics(JAP). So I'm using using revtex4-1 document class `\documentclass[aip,jap,reprint,superscriptaddress,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4-1}`.

During the preparation of my paper, I use .bib file to generate my reference list. But now reach the submitting time, I want to embedded reference into my latex file as \bibitems. One method is to copy the content of .bbl file which is automatically generated by .bib file during latex processing.

Just as Jon commented, the content of .bbl file is controlled by documentclass. But the problem is that I found the .bbl file generated by JAP documentclass style is so complex , lengthy and unreadable. Something like:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{2}%
\makeatletter
\providecommand \@ifxundefined [1]{%
 \@ifx{#1\undefined}
}%
\providecommand \@ifnum [1]{%
 \ifnum #1\expandafter \@firstoftwo
 \else \expandafter \@secondoftwo
 \fi
}%
\providecommand \@ifx [1]{%
 \ifx #1\expandafter \@firstoftwo
 \else \expandafter \@secondoftwo
 \fi
}%
\providecommand \natexlab [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \enquote  [1]{``#1''}%
\providecommand \bibnamefont  [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \bibfnamefont [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \citenamefont [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \href@noop [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \href [0]{\begingroup \@sanitize@url \@href}%
\providecommand \@href[1]{\@@startlink{#1}\@@href}%
\providecommand \@@href[1]{\endgroup#1\@@endlink}%
\providecommand \@sanitize@url [0]{\catcode `\\12\catcode `\$12\catcode
  `\&12\catcode `\#12\catcode `\^12\catcode `\_12\catcode `\%12\relax}%
\providecommand \@@startlink[1]{}%
\providecommand \@@endlink[0]{}%
\providecommand \url  [0]{\begingroup\@sanitize@url \@url }%
\providecommand \@url [1]{\endgroup\@href {#1}{\urlprefix }}%
\providecommand \urlprefix  [0]{URL }%
\providecommand \Eprint [0]{\href }%
\providecommand \doibase [0]{http://dx.doi.org/}%
\providecommand \selectlanguage [0]{\@gobble}%
\providecommand \bibinfo  [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \bibfield  [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \translation [1]{[#1]}%
\providecommand \BibitemOpen [0]{}%
\providecommand \bibitemStop [0]{}%
\providecommand \bibitemNoStop [0]{.\EOS\space}%
\providecommand \EOS [0]{\spacefactor3000\relax}%
\providecommand \BibitemShut  [1]{\csname bibitem#1\endcsname}%
\let\auto@bib@innerbib\@empty
%</preamble>
\bibitem [{\citenamefont {Mazin}\ \emph {et~al.}(2008)\citenamefont {Mazin},
  \citenamefont {Singh}, \citenamefont {Johannes},\ and\ \citenamefont
  {Du}}]{10.1103/PhysRevLett.101.057003}%
  \BibitemOpen
  \bibfield  {author} {\bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {I.~I.}\ \bibnamefont
  {Mazin}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {D.~J.}\ \bibnamefont {Singh}},
  \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {M.~D.}\ \bibnamefont {Johannes}}, \ and\
  \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {M.~H.}\ \bibnamefont {Du}},\ }\href
  {\doibase 10.1103/PhysRevLett.101.057003} {\bibfield  {journal} {\bibinfo
  {journal} {{Phys. Rev. Lett.}}\ }\textbf {\bibinfo {volume} {{101}}},\
  \bibinfo {pages} {057003} (\bibinfo {year} {2008})}\BibitemShut {NoStop}%
\bibitem [{\citenamefont {Mazin}(2010)}]{10.1038/nature08914}%
  \BibitemOpen
  \bibfield  {author} {\bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {I.~I.}\ \bibnamefont
  {Mazin}},\ }\href {\doibase 10.1038/nature08914} {\bibfield  {journal}
  {\bibinfo  {journal} {{Nature}}\ }\textbf {\bibinfo {volume} {{464}}},\
  \bibinfo {pages} {183} (\bibinfo {year} {2010})}\BibitemShut {NoStop}%
\end{thebibliography}%
```

the appearance of reference is like this
[image]

Well, pasting such a huge block of data into latex file surely works. But it's unreadable.

Actually, if we use modified `unsrt` style mentioned here [Is it possible to get unsrt + abbrv bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5053/is-it-possible-to-get-unsrt-abbrv-bibliography). We can generate reference appearance quite similar to JAP style. The modification in done in `unsrt.bst` file. Since author name in the original `unsrt` is not JAP style. So by changing `ff~` into f.~ in `FUNCTION {format.names}`, we got JAP author name style. The generated .bbl file is much clear now as below:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{10.1103/PhysRevLett.101.057003}
I.~I. Mazin, D.~J. Singh, M.~D. Johannes, and M.~H. Du.
\newblock {\em {Phys. Rev. Lett.}}, {101}(5):057003, 2008.

\bibitem{10.1038/nature08914}
I.~I. Mazin.
\newblock {\em {Nature}}, {464}(7286):183--186, 2010.

\end{thebibliography}
```

[image]

To produce the exact JAP reference appearance. We can just done a few text substitutions like:

1. delete \em
2. delete (5) and (7286)
3. replace ":" as ","
4. add round brackets to the year.
5. bold 101 and 464
6. change 183--186 into 183

the above list of operations can be done easily with some regular expression substition knowledge. And finally we got the following \bibitems that produce exactly the same JAP reference style.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{10.1103/PhysRevLett.101.057003}
I.~I. Mazin, D.~J. Singh, M.~D. Johannes, and M.~H. Du.
\newblock {{Phys. Rev. Lett.}} \textbf{101}, 057003 (2008).

\bibitem{10.1038/nature08914}
I.~I. Mazin.
\newblock {{Nature}} \textbf{464}, 183 (2010).
\end{thebibliography}
```

**Just like changing `ff~` to `f.~` in `unsrt.bst` gives the right JAP style author name. I believe that we just need a few more modification to the `unsrt.bst` file to generate the right and clear \bibitems in JAP style in a single step, so I needn't any regex subsititution postprocessing.**

Comment: A few things: (1) I don't think that the `.bbl` file is not really meant to be human-readable: it is an intermediate stage used to get to the final output; (2) the `.bst` controls the production of the `.bbl`; if you are using a particular `.bst` supplied by the journal, it doesn't matter how convuluted the `.bbl` file is: that's what the journal requires and expects. (3) although *your* style seems to be fairly uncomplicated, most others aren't: so there it is very important that each little field of an entry can be manipulated properly via macros like `\citenamefont` and so forth.

Comment: @jon You are right. I have made great modification to my original questions, could you give any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think maybe I can answer my own question now.

The key to this problem is to generate a custom bibliography style bst file.

There are two ways to do it

1. use makebst tool in package [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib)
2. use java based software [bib-it](http://bib-it.sourceforge.net/)

`makebst` is a command-line tool to generate a custom .bst file after you answering a series of around 70 questions related to the format of the reference style you want. For me it is not so friendly, you can learn how to use it step by step by reading this article [LaTeX, bibliography management and styles](http://www.medicalnerds.com/latex-bibliography-management-and-styles/).

On the other hand, I found to use `bib-it` is much easier (Thanks to the author of `bib-it`). It has a `Bibtex style generator`, which is graphical. Now I will show how to use `bib-it` to generate a JAP style .bst file in just a few minutes.

---

Opening `bib-it`, click "tools-->style generator". you will see an graphical interface titled `Bibtex style generator`. What you have to do is a 3 steps setting shown in the following picture:

1. article
   [image]
2. book
   [image]

   3. author
      [image]

Finally, you just press "generate and save", you got your custom bst file.

The appearance of the generated reference is like 
[image]

and the .bbl file generated automatically is quite clear

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{10.1103/PhysRevLett.101.057003}
I.~I. Mazin, D.~J. Singh, M.~D. Johannes and M.~H. Du, {Phys. Rev. Lett.}
  \textbf{{101}}, 057003 (2008).

\bibitem{10.1038/nature08914}
I.~I. Mazin, {Nature} \textbf{{464}}, 183--186 (2010).

\end{thebibliography}
```

The only fault is the "pages", JAP only need start page. This can be fixed with a single substitution operation using regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the contents of your bib file at the start of your preamble (following the `\documentclass` line) using the `filecontents` environment.

```
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents} {mwe.bib}
@online{tab:test,
  author                   = {Doe, John},
  Url                      = {http://www.example.com/images/image.jpg},
  Urldate                  = {2014-02-25},
  Timestamp                = {2014.06.13},
  Note                     = {Table \ref{tab1}}, %<== this should point to your table caption label
  year                     = {2014}, %this is necessary for the in-text citation to work
}
\end{filecontents}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't make it work, could you explain it further?

Comment: @user15964 -- penguinpreferred is suggesting you embed your bibliography file in a `filecontents` environment (here with the name `mwe.bib`, so you'd need something like `\bibliography{mwe}`).  Then you run `latex`, which will behave normally *plus* create the file `mwe.bib`; then you run `bibtex` and `latex` twice more and it will use `mwe.bib` to populate your bibliography.  I suppose the idea is that you don't need to embed the `.bbl` this way.  But whether the journal will let you do this is another question.

Comment: The solution provided by @penguinpreferred avoids having to send more than a single file. But I'm not sure if that's what the user asked. If I'm not wrong, putting the content of the `*.bbl` file into the main avoids having to run `bibtex`, thus not having to check the `*.bib` file at all. Giving the `*.bib` file requires aditional compilation that the journal may not do.

Comment: @jon OK, I understand what you mean. Thank you very much. But I still want to embed the references as a list of bibitems. You can see I modified my question, maybe you have other suggestions.