# How do I display references on one line in a modification of unsrtnat

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am trying to have a bibliography that does a number of things.

**1)** Be able to cite with [number] using `\cite`;

**2)** Be able to cite with author [number] using `\citet`;

**3)** Have an unsorted (such that entries appear in the same order they are cited) bibliography

**4)** Have a condensed bibliography with each reference being just a single line, as in siam. The ideal formatting would be the one as in siam. I think it looks clearest.

I will list anything in the editor that I have with "bib" inside it, in case it's relevant.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,leqno,openbib,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnatmod.bst}
\bibliography{Mendeley}
```

The `.bst` file is based off of the instructions in [Is it possible to get unsrt + abbrv bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5053/is-it-possible-to-get-unsrt-abbrv-bibliography), but done using `unsrtnat` and `abbrvnat`, since I am using `natbib`. I am using the Mendeley reference manager.

I followed the instructions and it's giving me something with condensed macros (and one gigantic web url that flies off of the screen) but each entry is listed as if it were a slightly more formatted `.bib` file.

This is due in 47 hours and 54 minutes. I only just an hour ago learned that `.bst` files could be editted directly.