# How to make references appear from number [1] in the paper

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I am currently using

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{reference}
```

in the main script for referencing the references and also adding references in another .bib file as follows:

```
@inproceedings{kriukova2018using,
  title={Using explicit semantic analysis and Word2Vec in measuring semantic relatedness of Russian paraphrases},
  author={Kriukova, Anna and Mitrofanova, Olga and Sukharev, Kirill and Roschina, Natalia},
  booktitle={International Conference on Digital Transformation and Global Society},
  pages={350--360},
  year={2018},
  organization={Springer}
}
```

but the first citation in the paper does not start from number 1. How can I make it start from number [1]?

This is my whole main part:

```
    \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}
\usepackage{notoccite}
%\usepackage[numbers, sort&compress]{natbib}

% *** CITATION PACKAGES ***
%
%\usepackage{cite}
% cite.sty was written by Donald Arseneau
% V1.6 and later of IEEEtran pre-defines the format of the cite.sty package
% \cite{} output to follow that of the IEEE. Loading the cite package will
% result in citation numbers being automatically sorted and properly
% "compressed/ranged". e.g., [1], [9], [2], [7], [5], [6] without using
% cite.sty will become [1], [2], [5]--[7], [9] using cite.sty. cite.sty's
% \cite will automatically add leading space, if needed. Use cite.sty's
% noadjust option (cite.sty V3.8 and later) if you want to turn this off
% such as if a citation ever needs to be enclosed in parenthesis.
% cite.sty is already installed on most LaTeX systems. Be sure and use
% version 5.0 (2009-03-20) and later if using hyperref.sty.
% The latest version can be obtained at:
% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite
% The documentation is contained in the cite.sty file itself.







\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}


\begin{document}

\title{ggg}
%





% make the title area
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
gggg
\end{abstract}

% Note that keywords are not normally used for peerreview papers.

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
gggg
\end{IEEEkeywords}




\input Introduction.tex
\input RelatedWork.tex
\input System.tex
\input Experiment.tex
%\input Discussion.tex
\input Conclusion.tex

%\balance

\appendices
% use section* for acknowledgment
\section*{Acknowledgment}



%abbrv
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{reference}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include a complete [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: Probably you prefer the `unsrt` bibliography style?

Comment: Yes, `unsrt` is what you are looking for, but if this is optional,  you should left  `abbrv` , anyway . The references are sorted alphabetically in `abbrv` style and then the  citations are unsorted, while with  `unsrt` is the opposite. But whilst ordering references alphabetically could be of some help to the reader, ordering by place of citation do not help in any way.  Suppose that you want to find quickly Kriukova et al. among one hundred references, what style will be better for this?

Comment: @Fran: To be honest, I have never seen a document that uses a numeric citation style win combination with an alphabetically sorted list of references. Do you know a field where this combination is common?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5053/120578

Answer (score 1):

There are *many* bibliography styles out there which (a) generate numeric-style citation call-outs and (b) do not sort the bibliographic entries alphabetically by authors' surnames. Four of them are:

- `unsrt` -- One of the original BibTeX style files, dating back to the early 1980s. To ease some citation-related burdens, it's a good idea to load the `cite` package when using the `unsrt` bibliography style.
- `unsrtnat` -- A reimplementation of `unsrt` distributed with the `natbib` citation management package. Useful if your bib entries contain fields such as `url`, `doi`, or `isbn`. Be sure to load `natbib` with the option `numbers`.
- `ieeetr` -- Every bit as ancient as `plain`, `abbrv`, and `unsrt`. Be sure to load the `cite` citation management package.
- `IEEEtran`. Provided by the IEEE publishing organizations. Basically, `IEEEtran` is to `ieeetr` what `unsrtnat` is to `unsrt`. Be sure to load `natbib` with the option `numbers`.

Comment: I added \bibliographystyle{unsrt} and \usepackage{cite}
it only returns the first citation as [1] and the next citation is [8] not [2]

Comment: @Goli - And did you run a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more) after changing the argument of `\bibliographystyle`?

Answer (score 0):

I have used in the past biblatex in a way like:

```
\RequirePackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=trad-plain,citestyle=numeric,sorting=none,backref=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{[#1]}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list 
    {\printfield[labelnumberwidth]{labelnumber}} 
  {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}% 
   \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}% 
   \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5\biblabelsep}% 
   \setlength{\itemsep}{3mm}%\bibitemsep}% 
   \setlength{\itemindent}{\labelwidth}% 
   \addtolength{\itemindent}{\labelsep}% 
   \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}% 
   %\setlength{\listparindent}{-\labelwidth}
   }%
   \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1}} 
{\endlist} 
{\item}
\bibliography{references}
```

This code is not mine but I found and edited some time in the past, so please if someone find the real source (it was on tex.stackexchange.com) please inform me to add the source.

Comment: I added this and it does not work.